# Selecting rows in DataFrame by/after grouping using DataFramesMeta in Julia

Tags: linq, julia

I am trying to select certain data rows in a `DataFrame` using `@linq` macros:

```
using DataFrames, DataFramesMeta
df=DataFrame(x = ["a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b"], 
             y = [1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4], 
             z = [100, 200, 300, 456, 345, 234])

| Row | x   | y | z   |
|-----|-----|---|-----|
| 1   | "a" | 1 | 100 |
| 2   | "a" | 2 | 200 |
| 3   | "a" | 3 | 300 |
| 4   | "b" | 2 | 456 |
| 5   | "b" | 3 | 345 |
| 6   | "b" | 4 | 234 |
```

I am trying to select those rows that have the maximum `y` for a given type of `x`, that is

```
| Row | x   | y | z   |
|-----|-----|---|-----|
| 1   | "a" | 3 | 300 |
| 2   | "b" | 4 | 234 |
```

So, I am grouping by column `x` and adding a column with the maxima

```
@linq df |> @by(:x, maxY = maximum(:y))
```

which gives

```
| Row | x   | maxY |
|-----|-----|------|
| 1   | "a" | 3    |
| 2   | "b" | 4    |
```

but I don't see how to put the corresponding z entries back in. Probably, it would be `join` but I don't see how to do that or get the result in another, simple way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in one line joining `on=[:x,:y]` but for this to work you need to name the `maximum(:y)` column `y` not `maxY`:

```
df2 = @linq df |> by(:x, y=maximum(:y)) |> join(df, on=[:x, :y])
```

You can later rename that column to the intended `maxY`:

```
rename!(df2, :y, :maxY)
```

Comment: That's elegant. Thanks. So you strategically choose `y` as the name of the maximum so you can join on two columns of both the outcome of the grouping by `by` and df `:x` and `:y`.

Comment: Exactly, otherwise it would have been difficult. Glad to have helped - your question made me `@linq DataFramesMeta |> aware of |> learn` and I really like it. :)